# An error due to adding .innerHTML to an element and attempting console.log

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, console.log

I am starting to learn JavaScript and am constructing a rock, paper, scissors game with DOM manipulation.

So far I am trying to link HTML buttons to the player choices:

```
<div class="choices">
<button id="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

I am then using Javascript to try and capture the value of the buttons to use within the game function:

JavaScript

```
<script>
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (let i = 0; i <= el.length; i++) {
  console.log(el[i].innerHTML);
}
```

However, the above code delivers the following result in the console:

```
Rock
Paper
Scissors
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at 
ui_rps.html:38
```

So the array is returned, but there is an error? Can someone please help and explain why this is and how I can remove it?

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i <= el.length; i++) {` Javascript array-like objects are zero-indexed; `arrayLike[arrayLike.length]` should not exist. Change to `i < el.length`. Better yet, use `forEach` instead of a `for` loop

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Comment: A classical off-by-one error. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `for` loop to from `i <= el.length` to `i < el.length`. At the moment, it's iterating to one more item than you have.

For example, if you've got three items, then `i` will end up being `0, 1, 2, 3` – when you try and call `el[3].innerHTML = 'blah'` it won't work as `el[3]` is undefined.

Hope that makes some sense!

Comment: It does. I feel so thick for not realising! It now works, thank you very much.

Comment: @J.Day Don't feel thick – happens to the best of us!